# How to manage string with blanks, comma etc. as PathParam?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, path-parameter

I created a web services that needs to get a string with blanks, commas, parenthesis and other special characters. I would like pass it as PathParam but I wasn't able to manage this string.

The string that I want to manage is similar to the follow:

> POLYGON((9.5 44.6, 12.5 44.6, 12.5 42.0, 9.5 42.0, 9.5 44.6))

My method is:

```
@POST
@Path("/j_update_spi/{step}/{srid}/{polygon:.+}")
public Response updateSPI(@PathParam("step") String step,
                          @PathParam("srid") String srid,
                          @PathParam("polygon") String polygon){
...
}
```

i tried to set ".+" for polygon parameter but it doesn't work (i also tried to use .*).

If I call this service the method doesn't start.

Comment: So, are you saying as part of `polygon` you are supposed to pass  `9.5 44.6, 12.5 44.6, 12.5 42.0, 9.5 42.0, 9.5 44.6` ?

Comment: Is `POLYGON` part of the string?

Comment: @Ravi : yes, actually I created a method that get only the coordinates as simple box. But I need to get any polygons

Comment: @user1803551 : yes POLYGON is part of the string. This is the standard format WKT (WellKnownText) OGC compliant

Comment: The regex works, your problem is somewhere else. Post the request path.

Comment: Also post the class declaration and JAX-RS `Application` paths if relevant.

Comment: Thank you for answers, I solved my problem. I posted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem: I changed the PathParam "polygon" and made it as optional. Then I changed regex rules into polygon PathParam.

```
@POST
@Path("/update_spi/{step}/{srid}{polygon:(/polygon/.+?)?}")
public Response updateSPI(@PathParam("step") String step,
                          @PathParam("srid") String srid,
                          @PathParam("polygon") String polygon)
```

in order to extract the string that defines my WKT Polygon I used **split** method:

```
if(!polygon.matches(""))
     polygon = polygon.split("/")[2];
```